# Definition 5.6.6 in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: How to show that this notion is well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, inverse-function, monotone-functions

Here is Definition 5.6.6 in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> (i) If $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \geq 0$, we define $x^{m/n} \colon= \left( x^{1/n} \right)^m$. (ii) If $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x > 0$, we define $x^{-m/n} \colon= \left( x^{1/n} \right)^{-m}$.

And, here is Theorem 5.6.5 (Continuous Inverse Theorem):

> Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly monotone and continuous on $I$. Then the function $g$ inverse to $f$ is strictly monotone and continuous on $J \colon= f(I)$.

However, the above theorem (perhaps also on the basis of the proof given by Bartle & Sherbert) could be restated more elaborately as follows:

> Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, and let $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing (respectively strictly decreasing) continuous function. Then the range $f(I)$ of function $f$ is also an interval $J \subset \mathbb{R}$; $f$ is a bijective mapping of the interval $I$ onto the interval $J$; and the inverse function $g \colon J \to I$ is also a strictly increasing (respectively strictly decreasing) continuous function.

Am I right? I mean is there any problem with the result I've just stated?

Now suppose $n$ is a given natural number. Then as the function $f \colon [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) \colon= x^n$ is a strictly increasing continuous function, and the range of $f$ equals $[0, +\infty)$ also, so the inverse $g$ of $f$ exists and is a function $g \colon [0, +\infty) \to [0, +\infty)$ that is also strictly increasing and continuous (on all of $[0, +\infty)$). This function is called the $n$-th root function. We write $$ g(x) = x^{1/n} \ \mbox{ for all } x \in [0, +\infty). $$
Thus, for each $x \in [0, +\infty)$, we have 
$$ g\big( f(x) \big) = x \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad f\big( g(x) \big) = x, $$
which is the same as 
$$ \left( x^n \right)^{1/n} = x \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \left( x^{1/n} \right)^n = x. $$
The proof uses the fact that since $n$ and $q$ are natural numbers and since $x > 0$, therefore 
$$ \left( x^n \right)^q = x^{nq} = \left( x^q \right)^n. $$

Am I right?

So far so good!

On the basis of this wherewithal, how to prove the following?

**MAIN RESULT**

> Suppose that $x$ is a positive real number, and suppose that $m, n, p, q$ are integers such that $n > 0$, $q > 0$, and such that $$ \frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}. $$
>   Then $$ x^{m/n} = x^{p/q}, $$
>   that is, 
>   $$ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^m = \left( x^{1/q} \right)^p. $$

This result establishes that the notion of rational powers of positive real numbers is so to speak well-defined? Am I right?

I have managed to prove the following though:

> Suppose that $x$ is a non-negative real number, and suppose that $n$ and $q$ are natural numbers. Then 
>   $$ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^{1/q} = \left( x^{1/q} \right)^{1/n}. $$

I think that with the help of the result just stated the MAIN RESULT could be more easily established if Definition 5.6.6 were to be stated as follows:

**Definition 5.6.6 Modified**

> (i) If $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \geq 0$, we define 
>   $$ x^{m/n} \colon= \left( x^m \right)^{1/n}$. (ii) If $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x > 0$, we define $x^{-m/n} \colon= \left( x^{-m} \right)^{1/n}$.

Am I right? If so, then (how) can we show rigorously that these two definitions for $x^{m/n}$ are equivalent (which indeed these are)?

Or else, is there another more direct way of coming up with a proof of our MAIN RESULT using Theorem 5.6.5 (or the more elaborate version thereof) and Definition 5.6.6 in Bartle & Sherbert?

PS:

Using @bangs idea, we can proceed as follows:

Proof of MAIN RESULT:

> Let us put 
>   $$ N \colon= nq. $$
>
> Now as the function $x \mapsto x^N$ is a bijective mapping of $[0, +\infty)$ onto $[0, +\infty)$ and as $0 \mapsto 0$, so this function also maps $(0, +\infty)$ bijectively onto $(0, +\infty)$.
>
> Now using the familiar properties of integer exponents we find that
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left( x^{m/n} \right)^{N} &= \left[ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^m \right]^{nq} \qquad \mbox{ [ Definition 5.6.6 and the definition of $N$ ] }\\
> &= \left[ \left\{ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^m \right\}^{n} \right]^q \\
> &= \left[ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^{mn} \right]^q \\
> &= \left[ \left\{ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^{n} \right\}^{m} \right]^q \\
> &=  \left[ \left( x^{1/n} \right)^n \right]^{mq} \\
> &= x^{mq}, \tag{1} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and also 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \left( x^{p/q} \right)^{N} &= \left[ \left( x^{1/q} \right)^p \right]^{nq} \qquad \mbox{ [ Definition 5.6.6 and the definition of $N$ ] }\\
> &= \left[ \left\{ \left( x^{1/q} \right)^p \right\}^{q} \right]^n \\
> &= \left[ \left( x^{1/q} \right)^{pq} \right]^n \\
> &= \left[ \left\{ \left( x^{1/q} \right)^{q} \right\}^{p} \right]^n \\
> &=  \left[ \left( x^{1/q} \right)^q \right]^{np} \\
> &= x^{np}, \tag{2} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   But as $$ \frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}, $$
>   so we must have 
>   $$ mq = np. $$
>   Therefore from (1) and (2) we obtain 
>   $$ \left( x^{m/n} \right)^{N} = x^{mq} = x^{np} = \left( x^{p/q} \right)^{N}. $$
>   from which it follows that 
>   $$ x^{m/n} = x^{p/q}, $$
>   because both $x^{m/n}$ and $x^{p/q}$ are in $(0, +\infty)$ and because the function 
>   $t \mapsto t^N$ maps $[0, +\infty)$ bijectively onto $(0, +\infty)$.

Is this proof satisfactory enough? If not, then where are problems in it as far as accuracy, rigor, or clarity go?

Comment: I am a little confused about what you wrote just before "The main result." You say $$(x^{1/n})^n= (x^n)^{1/n}$$ and then you say the proof uses the fact that since $n$ and $q$ are natural numbers, $(x^n)^q= x^{nq}=(x^q)^n$.  But $q=1/n$ is not a natural number. 

Also, the route you are taking yields that $(x^{1/n})^n=x=(x^n)^{1/n}$ not by the fact that $(x^q)^n=x^{qn}$, but by your very definition of $x^{1/n}$ as the inverse of $x^n$.

Comment: We know that on the domain $[0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto x^n$ is a bijection, and therefore so is its inverse. Therefore to show that $x^{p/q}=x^{m/n}$ it is sufficient to show that if I raise each side to the $qn$ power, the resulting expressions are equal. This should reduce to proving that $x^{pn}=x^{qm}$, which follows from $p/q=m/n$.

Comment: @bangs please read my post carefully and I'm sure you'd come to see the complexity of what is involved here. Or, can you please write out all the details in a full-fledged answer?

Comment: @bangs can you please take time having a look at my post once again? Using your idea, I've added the proof in a PS. Is this proof correct according to you?

Comment: The proof of the main result looks good.